# Removing character and adding new line

Tags: java, string

I want remove a character in a string and add a new line. 
How do I do that?

For example if there is a string like

`"are you ready?~Here we go"`

it should be written like `"are you ready?*newline*Here we go"`

I have clear logic of doing this by using charAt but I dont know how to remove the **~** character from the string.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: You have a `String` object and you would like to `replace` characters. Look through the API for Java SE 7/8 ;)

Comment: 'int i = 0;

        int length = text.length();

        while (i < length) {
            
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '~') {
                ch = '\n';

            }
            out.print(ch);

            i++;
        }'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`String#replace`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) will do

```
String data="are you ready?~Here we go";    
data=data.replace("~", "\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the char `~` you just can use the java function [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), or [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), if you want to that just for the first occurrence :

```
String my_new_str = my_str.replaceAll("~", "\n");
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Regular expression or `replaceAll` method if you want to replace all ~ characters with new line.
For new line - use `line.separator` property.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator").

String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
s.replaceAll("~", newLine);
```

Comment: You are not using any regex, so no need to use replaceAll for this. replace will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String s = "are you ready?~Here we go";
    s = s.replace("~", "\n");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it simple and straight forward?

> String new = "are you ready?~Here we go".replace("~", "\n");

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
String myStr = "are you ready?~Here we go";
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("~", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

find the character(~) & replace your character(\n)

```
your_string = your_string.replace('~','\n')
```

hope this may help